# trying to use a trait but keeps saying not found

Tags: php, class, oop, traits

I have a api trait that connects to an external endpoint. I want to use this trait in a class called ProductClass. The trait is in the same folder as the class, but I get a error is I add use ApiTrait in the class. Error says it cannot find the trait, So if I include the trait file at the top of the class file, I get this error, cannot find ApiTrait in 
ProductClass\ApiTrait.
If i pass the trait into the constructor I get an error from my index page when I call the ProductClass because I am not passing in the trait. I dont want to pass any params to the constructor just the string top append to the .env endpoint. any clues greatly appreciated
heres my ApiTrait code

```
<?php
namespace ApiTrait;

require './vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

trait ApiTrait
{
    protected $url;
    protected $client;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->url =  getenv('API_URL');
    $this->client = new Client();

  }

  private function getResponse(String $uri = null)
  {
    $full_path = $this->url;
    $full_path .=$uri;
    try {
        $response = $this->client->get($full_path);    
    }
    catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
    }
    return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

  }
  public function getAPIData($uri)
  {
    return $this->getResponse($uri);
  }
}
```

this is my ProductClass code

```
<?php

namespace ProductClass;
include_once("ApiTrait.php");

use DataInterface\DataInterface;

class Product implements DataInterface
{ 
    use ApiTrait\ApiTrait
    private $api;

    public function __construct(ApiTrait\ApiTrait $apiTrait) {
       $this->api = $apiTrait;
    }

    private function getResponse($append, $try) {
        $urlAppend = $append; 
        $good_data = false;

        do{
          try{
            $result = $this->api->getAPIData($urlAppend);
            //check data to see if valid
            if(!array_key_exists( "error",$result)){
                $good_data = true;
                return $result;
            }
          }
          catch(Exception $e){
            //call api upto 10 times
            if($try < 10) {
                sleep(1);
                getData($append, $try++);
            } else { //return a connection  error
                $api_error['error']='unable to connect to api';
                return  $api_error;
            }
        }
      } while($good_data === false);
  }

  public function getData($append, $try = 0)
  {
     return $this->getResponse($append, $try);
  }

}
```

Comment: You cannot pass traits in the constructor, that's just syntactically incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an autloader, you shouldn't ever need this:

```
include_once("ApiTrait.php");
```

You've got your trait defined in the ApiTrait namespace:

```
namespace ApiTrait;
trait ApiTrait { ... }
```

I.e., the trait's full path is `\ApiTrait\ApiTrait`. If you're using the trait in a namespace other than the one it's defined, then you need to anchor from the root namespace when referring to it, by preceding it with a backslash:

```
namespace ProductClass;
class Product implements DataInterface
{ 
    use \ApiTrait\ApiTrait;
```

Otherwise, if you do `use ApiTrait\ApiTrait;` without the leading backslash, then PHP thinks you're referring to the current namespace, which is `ProductClass`, yielding `\ProductClass\ApiTrait\ApiTrait` -- which doesn't exist, hence your error.

You could also do it this way with class aliases:

```
namespace ProductClass;
use ApiTrait\ApiTrait;
class Product implements DataInterface
{ 
    use ApiTrait;
```

Also, it looks like you're just putting every class it its own namespace. Don't do that. Use namespaces to group common items, for example, something like this:

```
namespace Traits;
trait Api { ... }

namespace Traits;
trait Foo { ... }

namespace Traits;
trait Bar { ... }

namespace App;
class Product {
    use \Traits\Api;
    use \Traits\Foo;
    use \Traits\Bar;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever used a leading slash in a use statement.

Comment: Probably because you're doing a `use Foo\Bar\Trait` alias declaration before the class definition (which is defined to be root anchored already) and then just the short form `use Trait` inside the class?

Comment: I only ever use it at the top, yes. The third paragraph seems to suggest you want the slash everywhere the namespace is used. At least I read it that way.

Comment: I think you're confusing the class alias declaration with the trait usage declaration. The `use` keyword outside a class definition is an alias declaration and never has a preceding backslash. The `use` keyword inside a class definition is a trait declaration. If you don't use a preceding backslash there, then you either need to be in the same namespace where the trait was defined, or have declared an alias for it via the aforementioned use of the `use` keyword.

Comment: _If you're using the trait in a namespace other than the one it's defined, then you need to anchor from the root namespace when referring to it, by preceding it with a backslash:_ When reading this, i got the impression that leading slashes are needed if the first root in the namespace differs from the current one. It's true, unless it was imported with a standard use statement (import, resolution) at the top of the file, which would not specify a leading slash.

Comment: I get what you're saying, I just think someone with less experience will not see the difference.